# Setting up SaltStack for local masterless development?

Tags: python, salt-stack

I am trying to set up [Salt Stack](https://github.com/saltstack/salt) for local development, but in masterless mode.

I have copied my states (`top.sls`, `mystate.sls`) to /srv/salt.

I have followed the instructions on the [local development page](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/development/hacking.html) and the [salt masterless quickstart page](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/tutorials/quickstart.html), but when I run

```
$ sudo /home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/myenv/bin/salt-call -c /home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/myenv/etc/salt --local salt.highstate -l debug
```

All I get is

```
[DEBUG   ] Could not LazyLoad salt.highstate
'salt.highstate' is not available.
```

I'm running salt in a vagrant `ubuntu/trusty64` virtualbox virtual machine on a Mac.

It seems like other modules load (I see them in the debug listing) but for some reason highstate (`highstate.py`?) is not being loaded.

What am I doing wrong? Is there something additional I have to do for masterless development?

Comment: Is your venv activated?

Comment: @rfkortekaas When I `su` to root and then activate the virtualenv (`source /home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/myenv/bin/activate`) I get the same results.

Answer (score 2):

I got help on `#salt` IRC channel from `whytewolf` - the problem was that the command should be `state.highstate` (not `salt.highstate`):

```
$ sudo /home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/myenv/bin/salt-call -c /home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/myenv/etc/salt --local state.highstate -l debug
```

Problem solved!